# Permiso denegado en store procedure

Tags: sql-server

Hola intento ejecutar un store procedure, sin embargo, obtengo este error "Se denegó el permiso EXECUTE en el objeto 'sp_AnalisisCobranza_Presupuesto', base de datos 'DB_MAVIJU', esquema 'dbo' ".
Mi store procedure es el siguiente:

> exec sp_AnalisisCobranza_Presupuesto 2020,2,10

Answer (score 1):

Si obtienes un mensaje de denegación de permiso, es porque no tienes permisos. El usuario con el que haces la conexión, no puede ejecutar ese sp. Parece una denegación explicita.

[image: Resultado]